# center three divs side by side

Tags: html, css

I have three divs that I want to center side by side on a page. I also have some content such as `<p>` and `<h3>` tags in them

HTML (example)

```
<div id = "wrapper">

    <div class = "aboutleft"> 
        <h1> About us </h1>
        <h3> small description </h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tristique non odio nec 
            A few sentences about you go here 
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class = "vline"></div>

    <div class = "aboutright">
        <h1> About the shop/Clients </h1>
        <h3> small description </h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tristique non odio ne
            A few sentences about you go here 
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.aboutleft
{
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    width: 450px;       
}

#wrapper
{
    text-align:center;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0, auto;    
}
.aboutright
{
    display: inline-block;
    float:right;
    width: 450px;
}

.vline
{
    background: rgb(186,177,152);
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    min-height: 250px;
    margin: 0 30px;
    width: 1px;
}
```

The result of this is just the 3 divs all floating mostly to the left. I want to center all three of them on the page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try it without `float` and with `text-align:center;` on the `#wrapper`. Since your blocks are `display:inline-block;`, they'll center the same way text does.

Note that nto make it responsive, I swapped all your widths to `%` instead of `px` and removed some extra `margin` spacing. I've also added `vertical-align:top;` so the divs aline along the top.

```
#wrapper{
    text-align:center;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.aboutleft,
.aboutright{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    width: 48%;
}
.vline{
    background: rgb(186,177,152);
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    min-height: 250px;
    margin: 0;
    width: 1px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/Ce3Uz/2/

Answer (score 1):

Yes

```
margin: 0 auto
```

without the comma

but also your divs should probably *all* have

```
float: left
```

as well. Then they will flow from the left across the page.

Wing

Answer (score 0):

Don't use , in the margin. Using this in your css for .wrapper will solve the issue.

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Also, if you are using absolute widths for the children of wrapper, you might as well use a fixed value for wrapper as well, as that will center the div wrt the children.

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove your floats.  Using `text-align:center` on the wrapper will align your `display:inline-block` elements side by side just like that.

I made a fiddle with your content doing just that. I also added a 'centerstuff' div where you should put the center content in, and made the widths smaller so it's more visible.

http://jsfiddle.net/rNcHY/

it's just `margin: 0 auto`, as others have noted.