# How do I center 3 divs that are next to each other?

Tags: html

How do I center 3 divs that are next to each other(float)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [center three divs side by side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17583185/center-three-divs-side-by-side)

Answer (score 1):

put them in a table with one row and three cells.... or wrap another div around them.

Comment: you should refrain from using tables to layout html. Tables are to be used for tabular data only

Answer (score 0):

if the divs have a fixed width you can float them left or right and wrap them in a container. Then set that container to be the combined width(s) of all 3 boxes and set `margin: auto` on the container. Or you can set each box to `display: inline-block` and call `text-align: center` on the parent

[FLOATING](http://jsfiddle.net/kpAA9/)

[INLINE-BLOCK](http://jsfiddle.net/kpAA9/1/)

Answer (score 0):

here the example

```
.container{
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}

.container div{
    display: inline-block;
    width:30%;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to float the 3 blocks, then you'll need another div to center, with those blocks inside.

HTML

```
<section class="thing-w">
    <div class="thing">Thing</div>
    <div class="thing">Thing</div>
    <div class="thing">Thing</div>    
</section>
```

CSS

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


.thing-w {
    width: 900px;
    margin-right: auto; /* centers the wrapper */
    margin-left: auto;
}

.thing {
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
}
```

a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/9LzBk/)

If you don't know their sizes... then I would suggest using inline-block elements and setting the outer wrapper to `text-align: center` - which will treat the blocks like inline elements and allow you center them... then you can also use `vertical-align: middle` to get some vertical align going as well.

Comment: Whats the*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

Comment: The * is a wildcard selector that selects everything. The box-sizing changes the box model, and moves the padding and borders *inside* the box. Now you don't have to add... 1px border left... + 1px on the right... and then another... and the box is 400px... so etc... etc... if you make the box 400px, it'll be 400px with or without padding. Google it for more info.

Comment: See this thread for inline-block centering:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22124163/css-image-gallery-will-not-center/22124594#22124594